Hide long filter in Postgres explain output
Let's say I have the following query on Postgres v15:
select * from table where id in (1, 2, 3, ...);

I want to analyze this query with EXPLAIN. Here's what the output looks like if the "IN" list is 3 items:
Index Scan using my_index on table  (cost=0.11..76.38 rows=36 width=100)
  Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::uuid[]))"

However, my "IN" list is extremely long (~1 million items). I want to analyze this query with explain but the output is massive because of the long list filter and my code editor can't render it.
Is there anyway to tell EXPLAIN not the display the long list filter in the output?


I would think that this ...my "IN" list is extremely long (~1 million items). is an issue in itself. I would put those values in a temp table and join against them. 2) Not seeing how this '{1,2,3}'::uuid[] can be valid?


However, my "IN" list is extremely long (~1 million items). You already know what the problem is... Use a temp table to fix this.

Sounds like a tooling problem.  What code editor does you use and how do you get the text into it?

Move your list to a CTE with VALUES in it. EXPLAIN will just show an InitPlan that results in a $0, hiding the actual list:
demo at db<>fiddle
explain analyze verbose
with cte(id) as (values(1),(2),(3))
select v from t
where id=any(array(select id from cte));




QUERY PLAN




Seq Scan on public.t  (cost=0.04..38.61 rows=62 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)


Output: t.v


Filter: (t.id = ANY ($0))


InitPlan 1 (returns $0)


->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=4) (never executed)


Output: "*VALUES*".column1


Planning Time: 0.413 ms


Execution Time: 0.078 ms



Consider using a temp table or rethinking this approach entirely - I don't think passing a million uuids this way is a good idea, especially if you precede this by pulling all of them out of the same db - in that scenario you could join instead.
If you want to run this twice, you're transferring the 1M uuid array twice - if it was in a (temp) table, you could just re-use it.
